# How to reassigns language settings and launcher shortcuts in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I'd like to use language settings as I used to:

- **Win** key switches to the first layout
- **Alt+CapsLock** switches to the next (without toggling the caps lock)
- Language settings valid per window
- **Alt+Space** opens the launcher menu

Currently **Alt+CapsLock** switches the layout, but the **CapsLock** toggled as well and **Win** key is not re-definable and opens the launcher menu

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL or *end-of-life* (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months

Comment: Same valid for 19.10

Comment: Unity 0r GN0ME??

Comment: Any of them. I'll use that supporting the feature

Comment: No.. You tagged unity in question.. The work around will be based 0n unity 0r GN0ME..

Comment: Ok. Removed the tag

Comment: Ok.. using default 19.10 I will try what you are looking for..

Comment: @RobertNavado workaround almost done with installing a simple package and prepared scripts.. small clarification.. launcher means? and when pressing Alt Space.. do you want to toggle launcher and normal state?

Comment: Same as happens when Win key pressed

Comment: That's overview.. Ok i will post the workaround..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Note:***

Tried this in Ubuntu 18.04.3.. similar to 19.10 Also.. (If you find difficulty.. I shall Install 19.10 and test it)

***Workaround:***

> Alt+CapsLock switches to the next (without toggling the caps lock)

use gnome-tweak tool to choose this.. It will not toggle caps_lock.
If you dont have gnome-tweak tool. Install it by below command.

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

[image]

> Alt+Space opens the launcher menu

go to keyboard shortcuts..
disable the default keyboard shortcut Alt+Space

[image]

Create a Custom Shortcut with below details

Name: Toggle Overview
Command: `/bin/bash /home/<yourusername>/tgov.sh`
{ example: `/bin/bash /home/pratap/tgov.sh` }

[image]

create a script in your home folder `tgov.sh` (toggle overview) with below content

```
#!/bin/bash

status=`gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'Main.overview.visible'`

if [ "$status" == "(true, 'false')" ]; then

dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.overview.show()'
else
dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.overview.hide()'
fi
```

[image]

> Win key switches to the first layout

1. Disable the overlay function from Super key..

`gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ''`

2. Create a Custom Shortcut key `Super+F` with below details

Name: Switch to First Language
Command:

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[0].activate()"
```

[image]

3. Install the package `xcape` with below command.

`sudo apt install xcape`

4. Make the Super_L key behave like pressing two keys Super_L+F

`xcape -e 'Super_L=Super_L|f'`

5. Create a startup applications preferences like below

[image]

> Language settings valid per window

use system settings to configure like below

[image]

Comment: Well, It's almost there.
Win key is not working when user not logged in (on lock screen)

Comment: Alt-capslock working there.

Comment: Among default shortcuts in settings Alt+Caps-Lock appears. Might you hace an idea How to get rid of toggling  Caps-Lock if using system shortcut? The main difference between methods is that with system settings it shows nice big icon when switching language.

Comment: It was the setting inherited from older version. I have chained upgrade from 14.04 moving several computers sice then...

Comment: Does it toggle Caps-Lock as well?

Comment: So odd to work hard to resemble 10 years old default behaviour

Comment: The true way was to switch to plasma desktop where these works out of the box