# Trying to set hot corner as overview and super key as view applications

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, settings

By default, the two do the same thing but I want the hot corner to be set as overview and super key as application view.

I found some solutions like [this gnome extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1198/start-overlay-in-application-view/) but it sets both the hot corner and super key as application view.

I also found a configuration setting:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-application-view "['Super_L']"
```

It successfully set the super key to application view and the hot corner remained as overview but when I press the super key again, it opens overview instead of closing application view. So to close application view, I'd have to press ESC twice (first opens overview, second closes it) rather than pressing the super key again.

Any thoughts?

Comment: have you tried `xcape` app which has to be installed and configure?

Answer (score 1):

**Tested in gnome-shell 3.38.0**

you can use below script to toggle showapps

```
#!/bin/bash

status=`gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'Main.overview.visible'`

if [ "$status" == "(true, 'false')" ]; then

dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.shellDBusService.ShowApplications()'
else
dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.overview.hide()'
fi
```

binding the above script to Super_L key is not possible in native way via keyboard shortcuts..

to have a workaround install `xcape` with the command `sudo apt install xcape` and configure Super_L with any other two combinations and set those two combinations as keyboard shortcut to run the above script.

you can have a idea from this post https://askubuntu.com/a/1219495/739431 under

> Win key switches to the first layout